# Why do I get an endless loop in MIPS (using QTSPIM)

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I'm new to MIPS and I'm trying to create a simple program, but I get an endless loop and I don't understand why.

I'm trying to point to a `size` variable with a global pointer and load it to $s1.

Here is my code:

```
.data 0x10000000

size: .word 0x00000001

.text 0x0400000

main:

lui $gp, 0x1000
lw  $s1, 0($gp)
```

The result I get is an endless loop.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no loop in there, but also you don't have an end to your program which might cause the loop. Add a `jr $ra`.

Comment: that gives several exceptions at PC = 0x00000000, bad address in text read: 0x00000000, exception occurred at PC=0x00000004, etc

Comment: ok I solved it. just added a loop at the end:
loop: j loop